# Any Tutorial to send Bitcoin from Copay to Trezor?

Tags: wallet, trezor, copay

I am using Copay wallet, and feel comfortable with it.
Now, the tricky part is to send my Bitcoins to my Trezor wallet.

Any feedback on the subject?

Regards

Comment: Can't you just get an address from your trezor wallet to send to?

Answer (score 1):

1. Find (one of) your Trezor address(es). Open this menu on your computer:

[image]

You can read the details here: https://doc.satoshilabs.com/trezor-user/receivingpayments.html

2. Open CoPay wallet, press "Scan" at the bottom. Scan the QR code shown on your computer.

[image]

3. Choose "Send payment to this address"

It should be easy from now on.